# PinterestSDK CocoaPods not working

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, pinterest

Has anybody recently successfully used the PinterestSDK CocoaPods?
This is the link I used as reference:
https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/sdks/ios/

I receive the below error:

> Pre-downloading: `PinterestSDK` from
>   `git@github.com:pinterest/ios-pdk.git`
>
> [!] Error installing PinterestSDK [!] /usr/bin/git clone
>   git@github.com:pinterest/ios-pdk.git
>   /var/folders/2m/87ls355x7_7b50b61d9h3lkr0000gn/T/d20150924-16277-16zcydf
>   --single-branch --depth 1
>
> Cloning into
>   '/var/folders/2m/87ls355x7_7b50b61d9h3lkr0000gn/T/d20150924-16277-16zcydf'...
>
> Permission denied (publickey).**
>
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>
> and the repository exists.

CocoaPods are installed, dependency added in the created Podfile, other Cocoapods don't return the error.

Does anybody have a workaround?

Comment: Found the answer myself, by mistake.
Instead of using the command:

pod "PinterestSDK", :git => "git@github.com:pinterest/ios-pdk.git"

I used:

 pod "PinterestSDK", :git => "https://github.com/pinterest/ios-pdk.git"

Both links are in the documentation(https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/sdks/ios/), but they seem unrelated.
They should update the page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Exactly this line in Podfile helps me to install Pinterest-SDK as Cocoapods:

```
pod "PinterestSDK", :git => "https://github.com/pinterest/ios-pdk.git"
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Pinterest SDK branch by MIT has been deleted or user specific, you can use a forked version:

```
pod 'PinterestSDK_5'
```

> This happens when installing pod asks for Github username.